# Window Creation in Beef Language

Tags: programming-languages, compiled-language, beef

So recently I have been learning about compilers and llvm and all of that kinda stuff. But what is really bugging me, is Beef. Beef is a cool programming language that I just learned existed but it is like C# Pro. But the one part I don’t understand is the window creation. Beef uses SDL which I get. (I have no idea how it links it) You can just create (on MacOS) an NSWindow and tada. But that is only supported in objective-c(++). So how on earth is beef able to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of the `WinBFWindow` class in [`WinBFApp.cpp`](https://github.com/beefytech/Beef/blob/HEAD/BeefySysLib/platform/win/WinBFApp.cpp), Beef calls [`CreateWindowExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw) function of the Win32 API to create a window.

Whenever [BFWindow.Init](https://github.com/beefytech/Beef/blob/5e5084886c4eed6ca12199d23cb4f3613ec3792b/BeefLibs/Beefy2D/src/BFWindow.bf) is called in beef, that is what eventually gets to that Win32 API call.

Comment: So I have been doing a lot of research and I believe that since beef is compiled it is just using c/c++ externs to handle win32 calls (it also uses SDL to simplify that process) Beef doesn't have to do much work. The linker is simply language independent. (for the most part)